# Types of cryptography

Tags: symmetric, terminology

We have cryptography based on hard problems from number theory, like DDH.

When we speak about symmetric cryptography with AES, a mode of encryption (CBC, ...), what is the type of problem ? What is the term used ?

Comment: You could say breaking symmetric encryption is a combinatorial problem.

Comment: The underlying problem is called AES. Typical symmetrical schemes don't reduce to an elegant mathematical problem. They rely on the complexity emerging out of the interaction of many simple operations. In a way RSA/DH etc. are structured whereas AES is unstructured.

Comment: You should read [Structure vs. Combinatorics in Computational Complexity](http://windowsontheory.org/2013/10/07/structure-vs-combinatorics-in-computational-complexity/)

Comment: @CodesInChaos The usual comment :)